# Google Identity Toolkit: Link multiple accounts?

Tags: google-oauth, facebook-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

I am looking for an "auth as a service" provider for my website that can let my users sign up using google/facebook and/or their own username/password. Trouble is, I am not able to find out if Google Identity Toolkit will automatically merge accounts if a user is using same email address for their facebook and google accounts. Also, does Google Identity Toolkit support forgot password functionality for user/pass auth?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Identity Toolkit will automatically merge accounts based on the email address. In some cases, Identity Toolkit will need to ask the user for their prior credentials before doing the merge. As an example, if the user previously signed in with email/password, then later signs in with Facebook, they will be asked to enter their password one last time.

Identity Toolkit will also help you send password-reset emails. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v3/required-endpoints#send_email_url) for enabling this feature, and is implemented in this [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go/blob/master/favweekday/favweekday.go#L278).